# Making a pause (sleep) in program - does not seem to function properly?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a code, where when a user presses a button, a message should display on a text area, and after 2~3 seconds, it should disappear.

Thread.sleep(milliseconds) should do this, but it doesn't seem to work (yes, I have it in try/catch and everything). 
Here is my listener:

```
 private class moveListener implements ActionListener
 {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout()); 

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if(e.getSource() == move[i][j])
                {
                    turn++;
                    if(turn == 4)
                        turn = 0;


                    text.setText(""+SPRITES[i]+" has used " + move[i][j].getText() );

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                    text.setText("");


                    cl.show(cards, MAIN);

                }
            }
        }        
}
```

When I run this I can feel the whole program freeze (probably due to sleep() method), but it skips the text.setText(theMessage) and goes straight to text.setText(""); 
In other words, where it should go Click > Display > rest > erase; it does Click > rest > erase.

I've tried other methods: which was doing the classic for(int i = 0; i < 9999999; i++) thing like 20 ish times, but that did the same thing as the Thread.sleep() way.

Any way to fix this? I've read something about it being bad to use UI with Thread but not sure what that meant.... any help is appreciated.

Comment: DON'T EVER SLEEP ON THE EVENT DISPATCH THREAD

Comment: "*When I run this I can feel the whole program freeze (probably due to sleep() method)*" - Not probably. That's **for sure**. DON'T use sleep, it blocks the EDT. Use `javax.swing.Timer` instead.

Comment: Try moving `text.setText("");` into the try block.

Comment: Thank you Doorknob and Maroun :).
I'll go read up on timers now haha

Answer (score 0):

```
           text.setText(""+SPRITES[i]+" has used " + move[i][j].getText() );

           Thread t = new Thread(){
                 public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                         text.setText("");
                         cl.show(cards, MAIN);                            
                    } );
                 }
           };
           t.start();
```

**The usual pattern is:**

There is "GUI thread", or EDT, or however you wanna call it.

The GUI thread does something with the GUI.

It then starts a new thread which waits a while.

In between the GUI thread can render other parts of the GUI, react on the mouse, and so on.

The new thread then wakes up and tells the GUI thread what to do by passing a Runnable object to the GUI thread (there are several methods for doing so, I am using a commonly used one here).

Comment: doesn't this still sleep on the EDT?